# Check if current thread is main thread

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

How can i check if the current thread is the main thread on linux? It looks like gettid() only returns an pid but it seems that linux does not guarantee the thread with main() always has a const and uniform pid.

The reason for this is that I have an automatic parallelization going on and I want to make sure pthread_create() is not called in a function that is already running on a thread that's created by pthread_create().

Comment: Have you tried syscall(SYS_gettid) instead? Remember to include sys/syscall.h

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Linux:

If `getpid()` returns the same result as `gettid()` it's the main thread.

```
int i_am_the_main_thread(void)
{
  return getpid() == gettid();
}
```

From [`man gettid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html):

> **gettid()** returns the caller's thread ID (TID).  In a single-threaded process, the thread ID is equal to the process ID (PID, as returned by **getpid(2))**.  In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID, but each one
>          has a unique TID.

From [`man clone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html):

> Thread groups were a feature added in Linux 2.4 to support the
>   POSIX threads notion of a set of threads that share a single
>   PID.  Internally, this shared PID is the so-called thread
>   group identifier (TGID) for the thread group.  Since Linux
>   2.4, calls to **getpid(2)** return the TGID of the caller.
>
> The threads within a group can be distinguished by their
>   (system-wide) unique thread IDs (TID).  A new thread's TID is
>   available as the function result returned to the caller of
>   **clone()**, and a thread can obtain its own TID using **gettid(2)**.

Comment: Thanks! Btw a side note on the linux machine i'm using gettid() is not defined. I found in another post which says using `#include <sys/syscall.h>
syscall(SYS_gettid);` to replace get gettid() and now it's working!

Comment: Storing the pthread_self id value is magnitude faster because this requires two slow system calls.

Comment: @Lothar: The values returned by `pthread_self()` and `gettid()` most likely are not the same. On Linux they definitely are not.

Answer (score 6):

What about using `pthread_self()`?.

This returns the `thread_id` of the calling thread. With this function, you can store the main thread id (when you know is main) and compare it later with other values returned from `pthread_self()` to identify if they are the main thread or another one.

Although I think is wiser to have well structured code. Something like functions to be executed in *slave* threads and other functions to be executed in the *master* thread. This is a better approach to this kind of problems.

Comment: The reason is that like I put in the original post I'm doing **automatic** parallelization which means I can not assume how an original given program looks like, so I need runtime check to see which thread that specific pthread_create() may be on.

Comment: that's why i need to check the current thread and not go with the easier route of writing a nicely organized program

Comment: @user2958862: Yes I tested and it is a very clean way to do it. I'm glad you could solve your problem :)