# Check if current thread is main thread, in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

This has been answered for [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411022/how-to-check-if-current-thread-is-not-main-thread), [Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546539/check-whether-or-not-the-current-thread-is-the-main-thread) and [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530218/check-if-current-thread-is-main-thread) before, but apparently not for Python. How do I reliably determine whether the current thread is the main thread? I can think of a few approaches, none of which really satisfy me, considering it could be as easy as comparing to `threading.MainThread` if it existed.

## Check the thread name

The main thread is instantiated in `threading.py` like this:

```
Thread.__init__(self, name="MainThread")
```

so one could do

```
if threading.current_thread().name == 'MainThread'
```

but is this name fixed? Other codes I have seen checked whether `MainThread` is contained anywhere in the thread's name.

## Store the starting thread

I could store a reference to the starting thread the moment the program starts up, i.e. while there are no other threads yet. This would be absolutely reliable, but way too cumbersome for such a simple query?

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The problem with `threading.current_thread().name == 'MainThread'` is that one can always do:

```
threading.current_thread().name = 'MyName'
assert threading.current_thread().name == 'MainThread' # will fail
```

Perhaps the following is more solid:

```
threading.current_thread().__class__.__name__ == '_MainThread'
```

Having said that, one may still cunningly do:

```
threading.current_thread().__class__.__name__ = 'Grrrr'
assert threading.current_thread().__class__.__name__ == '_MainThread' # will fail
```

But this option still seems better; ["after all, we're all consenting adults here."](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html)

**UPDATE:**

Python 3.4 introduced [`threading.main_thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#threading.main_thread) which is much better than the above:

```
assert threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread()
```

**UPDATE 2:**

For Python < 3.4, perhaps the best option is:

```
isinstance(threading.current_thread(), threading._MainThread)
```

Comment: `isinstance(threading.current_thread(), threading._MainThread)`?

Comment: That comment could be its own response :)

Comment: Is there any documentation about `_MainThread` though? Is that only part of one specific implementation?

Comment: Using attributes that start with an underscore is asking for trouble. Update 2 should say "For Python < 3.4, perhaps the best option is". Although for supporting multiple versions of python best may be to add your main script `if not hasattr(threading, 'main_thread'): threading.main_thread = legacy_main_thread_checker` with `legacy_main_thread_checker` using the "update 2" code of this answer.

Comment: this method is not reliable if process forked, [new main thread no longer a `_MainThread` instance](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/threading.py#L1334).

Answer (score 28):

The answers here are old and/or bad, so here's a current solution:

```
if threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread():
    ...
```

This method is available since Python 3.4+.

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, accessing protected attributes gives you the Heebie-jeebies, you may want an alternative for using `threading._MainThread`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207116/2016436). In that case, you may exploit the fact that [only the Main Thread can handle signals](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html), so the following can do the job:

```
import signal
def is_main_thread():
    try:
        # Backup the current signal handler
        back_up = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    except ValueError:
        # Only Main Thread can handle signals
        return False
    # Restore signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, back_up)
    return True
```

Updated to address potential issue as pointed out by @user4815162342.

Comment: This answer has good intentions, but the presented code has a problem which makes it unfit for production. The `is_main_thread` function has a nasty side effect of actually changing the `SIGINT` behavior to libc's `SIG_DFL` instead of Python's normal `signal.default_int_handler`. In other words, Python will **no longer behave the same** after an invocation of `is_main_thread()` that returns true. After running it, pressing ^C will no longer cause the process to be interrupted with a `KeyboardInterrupt` (which prints a stack trace and runs `finally` blocks), but will immediately exit.

Comment: @user4815162342 thank you for pointing that out. It seems to be possible to backup the current signal handler, and restore it before returning, thus keeping the signal handler intact.