# Need to Add Countdown Timer to Game using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, while-loop

I wrote a simple dice game on python and I want to implement a countdown timer to it! Which is an endless loop! Maybe some sort of thread generator? I am new to the threading module.

If I try to just add two threads to the game for each player: I receive 'RuntimeError: threads can only be started once' error

```
import random
import os
import time
from threading import Thread


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0

    def add_points(self, points):
        self.score += points


def roll_dice():
    min_val = 1
    max_val = 6
    dice_value = random.randint(min_val, max_val)
    return dice_value
```

thats my countdown times

```
def countdown(user_time):
    while user_time >= 0 and not done:
        mins, secs = divmod(user_time, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        user_time -= 1
```

the point of it: if a player doesnt stop the countdown, he loses

```
player1_name = input('enter name: ')
player2_name = input('enter name: ')
player1 = Player(player1_name)
player2 = Player(player2_name)
roll_again = 'y'



if __name__ == '__main__':
    while roll_again.lower() == 'yes' or roll_again.lower() == 'y':
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


        """ Player 1 """

        print(f'Hurry up {player1_name}')

        # new thread generated here

        input('press enter to stop\n')
```

if a player doesnt interrupt the countdown with an input - game over

```
        done = True
        # thread join
        player1_roll = roll_dice()
        player1.add_points(player1_roll)
        print(f'{player1.name} has {player1.score}')



        """ Player 2 """

        print(f'Hurry up {player2_name}')

        # new thread generated here

        input('press enter to stop\n')
        done = True
        #thread join
        player2_roll = roll_dice()
        player2.add_points(player2_roll)
        print(f'{player2.name} has {player2.score}')

        if player1.score >= 30:
            print(f'game over: {player1_name} has won')
            break
        elif player2.score >= 30:
            print(f'game over: {player2_name} has won')
            break

        roll_again = input('Roll Again? ')
```

Comment: Your issue is pretty much basic multithreading. In "while roll_again...", in each iteration you just create a thread that calls a function which uses a counter to count down. This post here can help you: [How to make a countdown timer that runs in the background, which terminates the program when it runs out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822346/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-that-runs-in-the-background-which-terminates-the) - if you just learn how multi-threading works in python, you can make your program work.

Comment: @Erdit I've tried that, but when the second iteration comes the program uses the same threads and :  RuntimeError: threads can only be started once!!  pops out

Comment: In python, a thread cannot be restarted once its been started and complete, you need to create a new `Thread` object for each player on each iteration of the while loop. If you've tried *this* and it hasn't worked, post your code above.

Comment: @Erdit I tried, but unsuccessfully. Actually THAT IS EXACTLY what i'm asking. (maybe worded the question wrong) how to create a new Thread object for each player on each iteration of the while loop???? (i'm guessing writing a function that will do that, but I cant figure out how)

Comment: What do you want to use that timer for? Print "took too much time, now it's your opponent's turn"? Or maybe end the game? In my opinion, your concept is flawed unless you can unblock the current thread after you call `input`. Remember, input is a blocking function that will halt the application until the user types something on the stdin, and presses enter. So, even if you have a timer (in a another thread or the same), if you don't have a way to unblock the input call, the timer is pointless.